# The Winter Bash hats. Why?

Tags: feature-request, etiquette

I have been issued several new hats. I do not like them because they are pointless. I would like to opt out.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the "snowflake" icon in the top bar.

Click on it.

At the bottom of the popup, there will be a button saying you want no hats.

This will turn off Winter Bash entirely.  You will get no hats and see no one else's.